# android InAppBilling: Purchase Signature Verification Failed

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, signature

Good day, After checking for solutions, thought i did ask here; i have an usual issue which i can't really get my head around. After successful doing a real purchase using one of my test account, i cannot purchase or initiate a purchase request to the Google Play service anymore with that same account(/device). i have unistalled the application both from my device and deleted it from the Google play console. Started the process of InappBilling, generated a new base64Encodedpublickey, checked to make sure its the same both on the Developer console and in my app and still i can't initiate a purchase request, i keep getting this error.

```
Failed to query inventory: IabResult: Error refreshing inventory (querying owned items). (response: -1003:Purchase signature verification failed)
```

i have done this process 3 times now and still i get this error on the device with the test account i purchased with. i have not tried it with another device with the test account(i really don't think it matters, but i will give it a go when i can).

***Note*:**on my other device with a different test account, i can initiate a purchase (even though i have not purchased yet cos i have not added any payment details there but at least i get there).

Anyone had anything like this before or have an idea what is going on?.. Cause its really baffling, some how, it seems that something is being stored but not sure? Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: please any one have any idea?..

Comment: I seem to have the same problem... have you managed to solve it?

Comment: I too have the same problem. Did u get any idea?

Comment: You can't purchase an item twice, to buy it again you need to consume it first